# Convert PointCloud2ConstPtr to PointCloud2

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tf2, pointcloud, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know how to convert convert PointCloud2ConstPtr to PointCloud2. I use these code:

```
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr kinect_pointcloud_ptr;
  kinect_pointcloud_ptr = ros::topic::waitForMessage<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/voxel_output", ros::Duration (5.0));
  std::cerr << "Pointcloud points number: "<< kinect_pointcloud_ptr->width * kinect_pointcloud_ptr->height <<"";

  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr p_pointcloud_ptr;
  tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
  tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped p_frame_to_kinect2_link;      
  p_frame_to_kinect2_link = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("kinect2_link", "p_frame", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(3.0));
  tf2::doTransform(kinect_pointcloud_ptr, p_pointcloud_ptr, p_frame_to_kinect2_link);
```

And I get some error:

```
Undefined reference to 「void tf2::doTransform<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> >(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const>&, geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)」
```

If anyone has good solution to suggest me. It will be nice.
Thank!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327473/convert-pointcloud2constptr-to-pointcloud2/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to use the [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#a29cf585a248dc53517834f4c5a1c4d69) to transform a point cloud, as far as I know it cannot be done using the doTransform method.

You'll also need to make a non const point cloud to store the result. Whenever you see a const type in C++ it means that its value cannot be changed. So you'll need to define a variable like `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 p_output_pointcloud_ptr;` for the result.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on 2019-07-02**:
Thank for your reply, it works for me. Here is my example code to provide to someone have the same question!

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pc;
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 t_pc; 
pc = *(ros::topic::waitForMessage<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/Topic_name",ros::Duration(3.0)));
pc.header.frame_id = "Source_frame";
pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("Target_frame", pc, t_pc, *tf_listener);
```

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-02**:
Great, glad you got it working.

**Comment by [alexe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30056/alexe/) on 2020-03-27**:
But why would you need to use `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud` if there are no PCL types involved? That seems to make no sense. Why wouldn't you use the `transform` method of the `tf2_ros::Buffer` object?